# Initialize all elements or std::array with the same constructor arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I am wondering if it's possible to initialize a `std::array` of objects with an implicitly deleted default constructor, without knowing a priori the size of the array because it's a template argument and so having lost the possibility of using an initializer list. Code follows, it breaks with a "call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of `std::array<A, 3UL>`"

```
struct A {
  A (int b, int c) : mb(b), mc(c) { }
  int mb;
  int mc;
};

template <size_t NR_A>
struct B {
  B (int b, int c) : 
    // <- how to initialize mAs here?
  { }
  std::array<A, NR_A> mAs;
};

B<3> inst(1,1);
```

edit: I'd like to initialize all the `A`'s of `mAs` to `A{1,1}`

Comment: How would you actually like to initialize `mAs` ?

Comment: Is `mAs{0}` what you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to initialize all A's to the same b and c arguments, 1,1. will edit the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For both C++11 and C++14 (i.e.: pre-C++17) what you want can be achieved by means of template metaprogramming.

You could declare the following helper class template, `array_maker<>`, which has a `static` member function template, `make_array`, that calls itself recursively:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t Idx = N>
struct array_maker {
    template<typename... Ts>
    static std::array<T, N> make_array(const T& v, Ts...tail) {
        return array_maker<T, N, Idx-1>::make_array(v, v, tail...);
    }
};
```

Then, specialize this class template for the case `Idx` equal to `1`, i.e.: the *base case* of the recursion:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct array_maker<T, N, 1> {
    template<typename... Ts>
    static std::array<T, N> make_array(const T& v, Ts... tail) {
        return std::array<T, N>{v, tail...};
    }
};
```

Finally, it can be used in the constructor of your template this way:

```
template <size_t NR_A>
struct B {
  B (int b, int c) : mAs{array_maker<A, NR_A>::make_array(A{b,c})}
  {}    
  std::array<A, NR_A> mAs;
};
```

Comment: I have chosen this as the correct answer because it achieves the same without C++17. v nice!

Comment: hmm this requires the copy ctor to be available, though

Comment: Prior to C++17 it is not possible to return a unnamed object that has neither *copy* nor *move* constructor, since *RVO* is an *optional optimization* in both C++11 and C++14. In C++17, the *copy elision* is however mandatory.

Answer (score 8):

You may use delegating constructors and pack expansion

```
struct A {
    A(int b, int c) : b(b), c(c) { }
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    int b;
    int c;
};

template <size_t N>
struct B {
  B (int b, int c) : B(b, c, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}) {}

  template<size_t... Is>
  B (int b, int c, std::index_sequence<Is...>) :
    arr{(Is, A{b, c})...}
  {}

  std::array<A, N> arr;
};
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/g/4dz3sp)

Note if the move and copy constructors are deleted, this will only work after C++17.

Comment: it's working on gcc arm. it's a multi-platform lib so if there was a < c++17 solution that'd have also been appreciated

Comment: @AlexDarsonik The limitation on C++17 is only if `A` has deleted move and copy constructors. I haven't figured out a way around that. If you own `A`, you could also have it take a `std::pair` as argument and instead expand on `std::pair`

Comment: I'd keep it deleted because it's a complex object. if I'll bump into a platform that doesn't have c++17 I'll just write the copy and move ctors

Comment: ps: gcc adviced to static_cast<void>(Is) in the template ctor of B

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution I came up with (requires c++17)

```cpp
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t index_t = N, typename T2, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto make_array_same_ctor(T2 t, Ts... ts)
{
  if constexpr (index_t <= 1) {
    return std::array<T, N> {t, ts...};
  } else {
    return make_array_same_ctor<T, N, index_t - 1>(t, t, ts...);
  }
}
```

This is a modification of one of the previous solution that had an array maker struct. This does the same just in a more concise form.

It takes in a single item and keeps doubling down on that item until it reaches a depth of 1,then returns an array from the unfolding. I didn't realize that you a fold expression can be used even though no arguments are passed through it. Although I know this implicitly from things like printf.