# Suppress warning "expression result unused" on a index_sequence

Tags: attributes, c++17, suppress-warnings

This question is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49318821/8769985).

The following code produces a warning of an unused value:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <size_t... I>
auto f(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  std::array<std::vector<int>, sizeof...(I)> res{(I, std::vector<int>(3, -1))...};
  return res;
}

int main()
{
  auto v = f(std::make_index_sequence<2>{});
  for (const auto& vec : v)
    {
      for (const auto& x : vec)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
      std::cout << '\n';
    }

  return 0;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0305986b6e0f2676).

With `gcc` 10.1.0 the warning is

```
main.cpp:9:52: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]

    9 |   std::array<std::vector<int>, sizeof...(I)> res{(I, std::vector<int>(3, -1))...};

      |                                                  ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

with `clang` 10.0.1 the warning is

```
main.cpp:9:51: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  std::array<std::vector<int>, sizeof...(I)> res{(I, std::vector<int>(3, -1))...};
```

(and some similar ones).

In `c++17` the attribute [`[[maybe_unused]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) should allow to suppress warnings on unused variables. However, putting `[[maybe_unused]]` before the argument of `f`

```
auto f([[maybe_unused]] std::index_sequence<I...>)
```

has no effect.

How can one suppress the above warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast `I` to `void` to discard the expression, and with it, the warning:

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, sizeof...(I)> res{
    (static_cast<void>(I), std::vector<int>(3, -1))...
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34289000/8769985), casting to ```void``` appears to be well defined. It's not clear to me what's the difference concerning the warning, given that you already discard the value with the comma operator.

Comment: @francesco Great that it worked! The warnings is there to just make you pay attention to something that may have been a mistake. When you cast you sort of say "I know what I'm doing".